# converting a project based solution to projectless website asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a rather large Web Application that I began to create using the "Web Projects" solution type in Visual Studio.

I  now have a need to incorporate some legacy VB.NET into the application, but low and behold you cannot mix languages using the "web project" model.  I have to use what is referred to as projectless development (which is basically just a single folder for the entire website).

Any idea on how I can covert a project to a projectless model?

I hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a web-site from a web application is relatively straight forward.

Open a new instance of visual studio

File > New Website

Select the folder that has your web application.

Visual studio will warn you that there is already a website containing files at that location.

Select Create a new web site at the existing location.

It will warn you that some files like `Default.aspx` exist. Choose not to replace them.

And you are done.

The reverse, creating a web application from a web site is difficult. So **be sure** before you make the change.